# php string name as variable

Tags: php

```
$string = "id";

want result to be like 

$id = "new value";
```

How do I code this in php?

Edit..

How about the below?

```
$column = array("id","name","value");

let say found 3 row from mysql

want result to be like this

$id[0] = "3";
$id[1] = "6";
$id[2] = "10";

$name[0] = "a";
$name[1] = "b";
$name[2] = "c";

$value[0] = "bat";
$value[1] = "rat";
$value[2] = "cat";
```

Comment: Although PHP does allow you to do this (as the answers below show), it generally considered a bad design principle and it makes your code a lot harder to maintain. A better approach is probably to use an associative array, for example `$my_array['id'] = "new value";`

Comment: You will have to create a seperate question for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second answer in response to your edit:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 0;
$id = array();
$name = array();
$value = array();

if ($num > 0) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id[$i] = $row['id'];
    $name[$i] = $row['name'];
    $value[$i] = $row['value'];
    $i++;
  }
}
```

This loops around your result, using the counter `$i` as the key for your result arrays.

EDIT

Additional answer in response to your comment:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  foreach($row as $column_name => $column_value) {
    $temp_array[$column_name][$i] = $column_value;
  }
  $i++;
}

foreach ($temp_array as $name => $answer) {
  $$name = $answer;
}
```

This code creates a temporary multidimensional array to hold the column names and values the loops around that array to create your variable variable arrays. As a side not I had to use the temp array as `$$column_name[$i]` doesn't work, I would love to see alternative answers to this problem.

Final note @Paisal, I see you have never accepted an answer, I wouldn't have put this much effort in if I had seen that before!

Comment: what if instead of define variable id,name,value manually, want to take it from $column array. I hope you under stand my point why I define $column array.

Comment: @Paisal I have updated my answer to create the column name variables dynamically. Bear in mind what @Marco Mariani said about the code being hard to read

Answer (score 9):

Theres 2 main methods

The first is the double `$` ([Variable Variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)) like so

```
$var = "hello";
$$var = "world";
echo $hello; //world

//You can even add more Dollar Signs

$Bar = "a";
$Foo = "Bar";
$World = "Foo";
$Hello = "World";
$a = "Hello";

$a; //Returns Hello
$$a; //Returns World
$$$a; //Returns Foo
$$$$a; //Returns Bar
$$$$$a; //Returns a

$$$$$$a; //Returns Hello
$$$$$$$a; //Returns World

//... and so on ...//
```

[@source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#97222)

And the second method is to use the `{}` lik so

```
$var = "hello";
${$var} = "world";
echo $hello;
```

You can also do:

```
${"this is a test"} = "works";
echo ${"this is a test"}; //Works
```

I had a play about with this on streamline objects a few weeks back and got some interesting results

```
$Database->Select->{"user id"}->From->Users->Where->User_id($id)->And->{"something > 23"};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
$$string = "new value";
```

will let you call

```
echo $id; // new value
```

Later in your script

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
$$string = "new value";
```

juste double `$`

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)?

That would accomplish something like this:

```
$string = "id";
$$string = "new value";
```

This produces a variable `$id` with the value `"new value"`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. Just use an array.

```
$arr[$string] = 'new value';
```

ref: [How do I build a dynamic variable with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077919/how-do-i-build-a-dynamic-variable-with-php)

Comment: Don't do variable variables? What's your reasoning for this, if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 0;

if ($num_rows) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach($row AS $key => $value) {
       ${$key}[$i] = $value;
    }

    $i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of us who need things explained in great detail...

```
// Creates a variable named '$String_Variable' and fills it with the string value 'id'
$String_Variable = 'id';

// Converts the string contents of '$String_Variable', which is 'id',
// to the variable '$id', and fills it with the string 'TEST'
$$String_Variable = 'TEST'; 

// Outputs: TEST
echo $id;

// Now you have created a variable named '$id' from the string of '$String_Variable'
// Essentially: $id = 'Test';
```